# PostgreSQL 8.2.9 Enum Type

Tags: sql, postgresql, enums, postgresql-8.2

PostgreSQL from 8.3 knows [Enumerated Types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/datatype-enum.html).

Simple question: Does 8.2(.9) know them too? If not, what can be used as replacement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enumerated types are not supported in 8.2.

As an alternative, use a `text` column with a `foreign key` reference to a table that lists possible values.

```
CREATE TABLE fruit_enum (
    fruit text primary key
);

INSERT INTO fruit_enum(fruit) VALUES
('apple'),('pear'),('grape');

CREATE TABLE basket (
    -- ... blah columns ...
    fruit text,
    -- ... blah columns ...
    CONSTRAINT fruit_fk FOREIGN KEY (fruit) REFERENCES fruit_enum(fruit)
);
```

This is the classic relational formulation, and is usually preferable to using an `enum` anyway. Enumerations are painful to deal with from some client applications and Pg doesn't currently support removing values from them either.

Here's how the above works:

```
regress=# INSERT INTO basket(fruit) VALUES ('apple');
INSERT 0 1
regress=# INSERT INTO basket(fruit) VALUES ('cider');
ERROR:  insert or update on table "basket" violates foreign key constraint "fruit_fk"
DETAIL:  Key (fruit)=(cider) is not present in table "fruit_enum".
regress=#
```

If you like you can indirect the enumeration via an integer ID, where the foreign key is to the enumeration table's ID not the enumeration value. Personally I'm not a fan of that approach, even though it's really only a true "enumeration" that way, because getting the value always requires an expensive `JOIN` or subquery, and there's typically little space saved.

Alternately, as @a_horse_with_no_name pointed out, a simple `CHECK` constraint is often sufficient:

```
CREATE TABLE basket (
    -- ... blah columns ...
    fruit text,
    -- ... blah columns ...
    CONSTRAINT fruit_in_allowed_list CHECK (fruit IN ('apple', 'pear', 'grape'))
);
```

Like the foreign key approach (but unlike enums) this is SQL-standard and should work on any database.

Also, seriously, *8.2*? That's [end-of-life](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) and woefully, amazingly out of date. Make urgent upgrade plans.

Comment: Good points! If the list of values is *really* static, one could also think about a check constraint.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Gah, I should've thought of that. Added.

Comment: Thanks for this exhaustive answer. We are using CentOS 5 which guarantees us a lot of stability and this comes with PostgreSQL 8.2. We know that it's out of date and are considering upgrading to CentOS 6.

Comment: @wnstnsmth Why not just upgrade PostgreSQL on CentOS 5? http://yum.postgresql.org/packages.php

Comment: We are actually considering this as well. The thing is that we have a lot of stuff that depends on PostgreSQL which we maybe would have to update as well.. but yes - we know we're out of date and we are trying to go forward asap ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Enums were introduced in 8.3
Here are the release notes: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/release-8-3.html

The data types for 8.2 are documented here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/datatype.html

But you shouldn't use 8.2 anyway (actually I wouldn't recommend 8.3 either)